# Can't change default settings in foundation theme

Tags: 7, theming

I am thinking about changing my Drupal site theme to a Foundation based one. I use Windows 7, with the Foundation module installed and activated, along with Ruby, Compass and Sass.

To experiment I have changed this in the scss files:

_variables.scss:

```
 $row-width: em-calc(1280);
 $column-gutter: em-calc(30);
 $total-columns: 12;
```

_init.scss:

```
$topbar-height: rem-calc(90);
```

I get no error messages when I navigate to my sub theme's folder and run `compass compile` from the command line. Instead I get this:

```
 write css/custom.css
directory css/foundation
 write css/foundation/foundation.css
 write css/foundation/normalize.css
```

... which looks promising enough. After this I added this to my sub theme's info file:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/foundation/foundation.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/foundation/normalize.css
```

I also commented out the app.css line in the info file:

```
; For CSS users, load the app.css file:
; stylesheets[all][] = css/app.css
; Comment the app.css file (above) if you're using sass to preprocess css:
 stylesheets[all][] = css/custom.css
```

I have looked in the page source and can confirm that those files are actually loaded.

The width is still is the default 1000px value and the top bar still have the same height (45). And yes, I have cleared all cache.

What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the noise... after a couple of hours of struggling I removed these lines in the info file:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/foundation/foundation.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/foundation/normalize.css
```

... and everything began to work. So never mind this question.